# Is it possible to conditionally specify a mocked object that is created after initialization?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, mocking

I am wondering if it's possible to create a repository as a mock version (in Swift, using Xcode 12.5) only for unit testing, when that repository is not set at initialization?

I am creating a viewModel that looks at two different types of objects (`Foo` and `FooTwo`), and depends on two different repositories (`fooRepository` (which has a factory type of `fooStoreType`) and `FooTwoRepository` (which has a factory type of `fooStoreType`)).

The `fooTwoRepository` is dependent on having a `featuredFoo`, too determine which 'FooTwo' objects should be returned. `featuredFoo` may not be set until the user takes some action (or at least until a downstream code flow completes), so I am setting the `fooTwoRepository(foo: featuredFoo!)` as part of a didSet whenever the `featuredFoo` gets set.

My issue is related to testing. I have a `MockFooRepository` and a `MockFooTwoRepository` for my unit tests. When I create the ViewModel in my test class, I can initialize my `MockFooRepository`, but since my `MockFooTwoRepository` doesn't get created until this didSet, I don't think I can create it this way.

Is there a good way to create this as the mock version only for unit testing in Xcode?
Or do I need to just create my `FooTwoRepository` on initialization, and have `featuredFoo` as an optional value so I don't have to set it right away, and then have it not do anything until `featuredFoo` gets set (and my didSet would just set `featuredFoo` in the repository for `FooTwo`)?

Here's my ViewModel:

```
class FooViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fooTwoRepository: FooTwoStoreType?
    @Published var fooRepository: FooStoreType
    
    @Published var featuredFoo: Season? {
        didSet {
            guard featuredFoo != nil else {
                print("Trying to set FooTwoRepository based on featured Foo. Featured Foo is nil.")
                return
            }
            
            self.fooTwoRepository = MyFooTwoRepository(foo: featuredFoo!)
        }
    }
    
    
    init(fooRepository: FooStoreType = FooRepository()) {

        self.fooRepository = fooRepository
 
    }
```

And for reference, my `FooTwoRepository` conforms to a factory method, `FooTwoStoreType`, which my `MockFooTwoRepository` also conforms to.

But it requires a `featuredFoo` to loadData, so I wait until the viewModel has gotten a `featuredFoo` to initialize this repository:

```
class FooTwoRepository: ObservableObject, FooTwoStoreType {

    var featuredFoo: featuredFoo
    
    init(featuredFoo: featuredFoo) {
        self.featuredFoo = featuredFoo
        loadData()
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the hard coupling between the view model and the MyFooTwoRepository type so the best way forward IMO is to break that coupling. One way is to create a factory type for MyFooTwoRepository and inject that in the view model and then use a mock factory when testing

Comment: Thanks Joakim - I updated my question slightly. I do have it set up that way, but I guess the problem is I'm waiting to inject it until something has been set in the viewModel, and that code doesn't have a good option for injecting a different repository that conforms to that factory protocol. It sounds like I will have to inject it upon initialization.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that seems to be working is to initialize the `FooTwoRepository` (based on `FooTwoStoreType`) right away, and instead have my `didSet` under `featuredFoo` trigger that same property to be set in `FooTwoRepository`.

Then instead, in my `FooTwoRepository`, I make `featuredFoo` an optional variable, I don't set it upon initialization, and I load my data under a `didSet` whenever that property gets set, instead of right on initialization.

Here's my class (I changed the `didSet` under `featuredFoo`)

```
class FooViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fooTwoRepository: FooTwoStoreType?
    @Published var fooRepository: FooStoreType
    
    @Published var featuredFoo: Season? {
        didSet {
            guard featuredFoo != nil else {
                print("Trying to set FooTwoRepository based on featured Foo. Featured Foo is nil.")
                return
            }
            
            self.fooTwoRepository.featuredFoo = featuredFoo
        }
    }
    
    
    init(fooRepository: FooStoreType = FooRepository()) {

        self.fooRepository = fooRepository
 
    }
```

And here's my repository, where 'featuredFoo' is now optional, and the `loadData()` function is called under a `didSet` there, instead of at initialization:

```
class FooTwoRepository: ObservableObject, FooTwoStoreType {

    var featuredFoo: Foo? {
        didSet {
            guard featuredFoo != nil else {
                return
            }
            
            guard fooTwoList.count == 0 else {
                print("Data already loaded. Skipping")
                return
            }
            
            loadData()
        }
    }
```